# Strange output on input to char* with different compiler

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I have declared and initialized a string in char* like below:

```
int length;
cout<<"Enter string length: ";
cin>>length;
char* str = new char[length];
cout<<"Enter your string here:"; 
for(int i = 0;i < length;i++)
cin>>str[i];
cout<<str<<endl;
```

Compile using DevC++, it give me what I type there, but in Visual C++ it print out  string with some random character at the end.For example; I type "hello" Visual C++ give me:"hello ^^&**(Y*&".Can someone explain to me why does this happen ?

Comment: *Can someone explain to me why does this happen ?* Because nobody's defined what should happen?

Comment: The statement 'cout << str' handles 'str' as a null-terminated C string. Append a '\0' at the end of str, or use 'cin>>str' instead of assigning every single char in str.

Comment: @ta.speot.is - I have explained it in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not null terminating the string.  You need to assign a char array of `length + 1` to allow room for the null character at the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks.I just started using VC , it seems that it handle string, array pointer much different from DevC.

Comment: @Husky That's because your code was bugged. It was wrong on DevC++ even though it ran correctly. As you learn more C++ you'll realise that correct programs run the same on all compilers but bugged programs run differently on different compilers. Sometimes bugged programs seem to run correctly, but that doesn't mean they're not bugged.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a null-terminator at the end of the string. I'm guessing non-VC++ compiler handles it somehow, but in VC++ you have to allocate length + 1 characters and then set last one to '\0'. Example:

```
char* str = new char[length + 1];

cout << "Enter your string here:"; 
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    cin >> str[i];

str[length] = '\0';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I don't have enough rep to upvote but I'll do when I can.

Answer (score 0):

You're never terminating your string.  Put `str[length-1] = '\0';`.

Or, better, you should allocate `new char[length+1];`.

IMHO...

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
for(int i = 0;i < length;i++)
    cin>>str[i];
```

to

```
cin>>str;
```

No `for` loop required. You can read a string as a whole instead of char by char.

Alternately, if you want to read it char by char, you need a `\0` to mark the end of the string because `cout` assumes that the string is terminated with a `\0`.

So essentially, you need

```
for(int i = 0;i < (length - 1);i++)
    cin>>str[i];

str[i] = '\0'.
```

You read `length -1` chars and the terminate it with `\0`.

Comment: If you want string with spaces, use `cin.getline(str, length);`

Comment: With string like str[256] getline() work correctly but with string char* and an int length like above VC++ doesn't work. right after I enter the length it skip input then output an empty string.

Comment: @Husky - As far as getline is concerned, there is no difference between `char str[256]` and `char * ptr = new char[256]`. The problem would be elsewhere.

Comment: I figured it out now.Since I have cin>>length above the cin.getline(),so after I pressed <enter>, cin.getlint() read this as an empty string into str.